# Counting lines in multiple logs file, filtered by date, output with filename

Tags: logging, count, grep, line, wc

I need to count lines in multiple logs file (/var/log/), filtered by date(07/Apr/2021:11), and show output with filename.

```
Expected output:
- file1.log: 25 matched lines
- file2.log: 36 matched lines
- file3.log: 56 matched lines
```

I counted it with "wc -l", I filtered it by date with grep -R path "07/Apr/2021:11"...
Now I want to merge all to show output like "filename: matched lines"

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -c "07/Apr/2021:11" /var/log/*
```

Answer (score 0):

[*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher*](https://crates.io/crates/super_speedy_syslog_searcher) can read multiple log files, then reprint log messages in a datetime range.

(assuming you have [rust installed](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install))

```
cargo install super_speedy_syslog_searcher
```

then

```text
s4 /var/log -a "2021-04-07 11:00" -b "2021-04-07 12:00"
```

would print all log messages during the 11:00 hour.

```
07/Apr/2021:11 hello
07/Apr/2021:11 something happened
07/Apr/2021:11 this or that
```

Then preprint each log line with the file name

```text
s4 -n /var/log -a "2021-04-07 11:00" -b "2021-04-07 12:00"
```

```text
log1.log:07/Apr/2021:11 hello
log2.log:07/Apr/2021:11 something happened
log1.log:07/Apr/2021:11 this or that
```

Then `cut` then `sort` then count (`uniq -c`)

```text
$ s4 -n /var/log -a "2021-04-07 11:00" -b "2021-04-07 12:00" | cut -f1 -d ':' | sort | uniq -c
      2 log1.log
      1 log2.log
```